# Keycloak cross data center partial synchronisation of user data

Tags: amazon-web-services, keycloak

I'm working for a german company, therefor we're bound to GDPR. We're selling our product as a software as a service offering and are hosting the systems in AWS. Our customers are spread over Europe, USA and Asia. So we're running multiple VPCs in AWS in the Regions EU-West, US-Northeast and APAC. Our plan is to implement Keycloak as SSO backend.

Up to this point our initial idea was to imlement Keycloak with the so called Cross Data Center Replication. This would mean one Keycloak-Cluster per VPC with a load balancer in front, the Infispan cluster for inter VPC caching/communication and an Aurora RDS cluster as the centralised database, but we are not pinned to that. The problem is, as mentioned above, we're bound to the GDPR and so the data of european users must not leave the EU except the customer orders us to do so. All I've read is saying that Keycloak is expecting that all data is synced accross the database cluster.

Information about our topology and the issue itself:
Every customer has dedicated EC2 instances in the best suitable geographical region. Additionally there are centralized services hosted in the EU. So user from the USA or APAC need to have access to systems in the EU but EU users don't need to have access to instances/services outside of the EU, except the customers explicitely orders it.

So how do we achieve this?

My only idea atm would be to build up a database cluster (likely not AWS Aurora RDS) and configure on the database itself to not sync all of the data. But this sounds very gross to me and I don't think, that Keycloak is doing well with this. Any ideas or tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in case someone is interested in our solution:
It seems, that we will accept the fact, that not EU customer have a latency under some circumstances. The Infinispan cluster will serve as a cache, so these users will only have once in a while this latency. The DB will reside in the EU. 
I'm not sure, if the Infinispan servers will act as a cache, if the connection to the nodes in the other datacenters is lost, but maybe I'll find something about that.